# How do I get out of Outline View?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, path

I have drawn a broom in Illustrator and cant apply any brushes or strokes to it. I just don't get it. What do I have to do? Here is a screenshot:

[image: Adobe Illustrator]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To get out of Outline View. Press <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> or go to **View** → **Preview**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  It doesn't matter if you are in Preview or Outline mode.  You still get an outline.  The solution is to hold down the crtl key and click on the eye in your layers menu.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

maybe try using the shape builder tool. Shift + m that will allow it to become its own shape and maybe then you can do it. hope that helps you.

Comment: How does that exactly solve the issue? Also, there is already an accepted answer for this very old question.

Comment: most irrelevant answer award.

Answer (score -2):

view -> Preview on CPU (or GPU Preview)

Answer (score -4):

Go to View --> and click Normal

Comment: There is no "Normal" under the View which is probably why you're receiving downvotes.

Comment: Hi user45353, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!